# Why is Simplification considered an inference rule instead of a replacement rule?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, formal-proofs

The wiki entry for Conjunction Elimination, sometimes called simplification elsewhere
$$
{\frac {P\land Q}{\therefore P}}
$$
is classified as an inference rule, rather than replacement rule.

This transformation feels closer to a replacement rule like double negation elimination, rather than an inference like Modus Ponens, because it operates on only one proposition, and doesn't seem to produce anything novel (at least as much as inference rules typically *seem* to do)

What are the technical reasons for this classification, and are there any thought experiments to see it as more intuitive?

After pondering the arguments for and against each choice, I'm left wondering if there is even a meaningful distinction between inference rules and replacement rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental difference between rules of replacement and rules of inference is that the former are based on logical **equivalences**, while the latter are based on logical **consequences**.

This distinction results in two major differences in how you apply them:

First, replacement rules can go ‘both ways’, e.g. a replacement rule based on the double negation equivalence $\phi \Leftrightarrow \neg \neg \phi$ allows me to infer $\neg \neg P$ from $P$, but it also allows me to go infer $P$ from $\neg \neg P$. On the other hand, inference rules go only ‘one way’, e.g. using Simplification you can infer $P$ from $P \land Q$, but trying to infer $P \land Q$ from $P$ does not follow the pattern of Simplification. And that is for good reason, since the former is not a logical consequence of the latter.

Second, replacement rules can be applied to component statements of larger statements. For example, using double negation you can infer $P \to Q$ from $P \to \neg \neg Q$. On the other hand, inference rules are only applicable the statement as a whole. So, for example, you are not allowed to infer $P \to R$ from $(P \land Q)\to R$. And again, that’s a good thing, since the former is not a logical consequence of the latter.

Finally (and maybe this can be regarded as a third practical implication of the fundamental theoretical difference), rules of equivalence always infer a statement from exactly one other statement, but rules of inference can involve any number of statements. As you point out, Modus Ponens takes in two statements, Constructive Dilemma (from $P \lor Q$, $P \to R$, and $Q \to S$, you can infer $R\lor S$) takes three, and Law of Excluded Middle (from ‘nothing’ infer $P \lor \neg P$) takes zero.  So, if you have a rule of inference like Simplification, which takes one, it may very superficially feel like a rule of replacement, but as already explained it really isn’t.

The only commonality between rules of replacement and rules of inference is that both can used to infer a statement from some other statement(s). As such, both kinds of rules can be said to be inference rules, but as explained above, rules of replacement are fundamentally distinct from rules of inference.

Answer (score 1):

See [Rule of replacement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_replacement): replacement is based on *equivalence*. Not every [inference rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_inference) has that property.

Specifically, in [Conjunction Elimination (aka: Simplification)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjunction_elimination) $P$ and $P \land Q$ are **not** equivalent.

Moreover, inference rules are not limited to a single premise; see e.g. [Modus Ponens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modus_ponens).

So, in conclusion, there is the class of *inference rules*, of which the *replacement rules* form a subclass.

Comment: This is reasonable. But trying to test it, could we not also argue that Modus Ponens is an equivalence expression, in that *mp(p→q, p)* == *q*, in the same way that given *f(x) = x+1*, then *f(1) == 2* and *2 == f(1)*?

Comment: Also, in your answer you give Modus Ponens as an example of an inference rule not limited to a single premise. I think you misunderstood my mentioning of single proposiiton; I was saying the opposite: I associate inference rules with 2+arity functions and replacement rules with unary functions. So given that Conjunction Elimination only takes one argument, it feels like a replacement rule.

Comment: You also say that replacement rules are a subclass of inference rules, which I take to mean that all replacement rules are inference rules while not all inference rules are replacement rules. Are you sure? The wikipedia entry refers to both of them as transformation rules, and presents them at the same level hierarchically in the table in the sidebar.

Comment: @pinkboid I suppose you could define Modus Ponens as some kind of function $mp$ that takes in statements and outputs another statement, and then say that $mp(p \to q, p) = q$ ... but that is simply not what we mean by a logical equivalence. A logical equivalence is a 2-place relationship between statements: two statements are (truth-functionally) equivalent if and only if under any truth-assignment to variables the statements have the same truth-value.

Comment: @pinkboid Also note that the equivalence relation is non-functional: e.g. $\neg \neg P$ stands in this relation to $P$, but also to $\neg \neg \neg \neg P$. Indeed, how would you define the double negation equivalence as a unary function?  Because it makes just as much sense to say that $dn(\neg \neg P)=P$ as to say that $dn(\neg \neg P)=\neg \neg \neg \neg P$

Comment: @pinkboid Finally, Mauro (and the Wikipedia page) mean to say that inference rules = rules of replacement rules + rules of inference$. So, every rule of inference is an inference rule, but not every inference rule is a rule of inference.